# Run DAG with tasks of different interval

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I have 3 tasks, A, B and C. I want to run task A only once, and then run task B monthly until end_date, then run task C only once to clean up.

This is similar to this question, but not applicable.  [How to handle different task intervals on a single Dag in airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440262/how-to-handle-different-task-intervals-on-a-single-dag-in-airflow)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For task A that is supposed to run only once, you can take inspiration from [here](https://medium.com/@plieningerweb/use-apache-airflow-to-run-task-exactly-once-6fb70ca5e7ec)

---

As far as tasks B & C are concerned, they can be tied up with A using a `ShortCircuitOperator` (as already told in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444637/3679900) you cited)

```
                   -> B
                 /
A -> ShortCircuit
                 \
                   -> C
```

Alternatively, you could skip B and C internally using an [`AirflowSkipException`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_skip_dag.py)

Comment: Much appreciated, this solves the problem quite beautifully. I had considered to break it into 2 independent DAGs and use Sensors to trigger a DAG when the other DAG is finished, but this solution is not as elegant.